# Add text depending on what text is already there using variable?

Tags: javascript

JS:

```
var textVal = 0;
function clickMe() {
    if (var textVal == 0) {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "TO";
        textVal += 1;
    };
    else if (var textVal == 1) {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML += " INFINITY";
        textVal += 1;
    };
    else if (var textVal == 2) {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML += " AND";
        textVal += 1;
    };
    else if (var textVal == 3) {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML += " BEYOND";
        textVal += 1;
    };
    else {
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "";
        textVal = 0;
    };
};
```

HTML:

```
<h1 id="txt"></h1>
<button onclick="clickMe()">CLICK ME</button>
```

---

I want to have a button add text depending on what text is already there. I am trying to use a variable to do so. My logic is that if there is no text, the variable is zero, so it adds the first word, then the variable will be raised by one so that the next time the button is clicked, it will use the next value, and so on until it is full, then it will empty the text and set it to 0 so that it will repeat. 
 I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong, it seems like it should work. Any help/tips?

Comment: As a starter, you don't need to declare the textVal variable each time you use it....

Answer (score 1):

Your general approach will work, except for some syntax issues, but you can greatly simplify.

```
// Get an array of words by splitting a sentence on spaces.
var words = ('TO INFINITY AND BEYOND').split(' ');

// Counter of the current word
var currentWord = -1;

// Define our click handler
function clickMe() {

  // Add one to the current word index
  currentWord++;

  // If we have gone beyond the number of words we have, reset
  if (currentWord >= words.length) {
    currentWord = 0;
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = '';
  }

  // Display the word
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML += words[currentWord];
}
```

I should also note that since you are setting HTML, you need to be sure that whatever you put into that HTML is escaped properly for HTML.  `&` becomes `&amp;`, `>` becomes ~>`, etc.  If you set the text properties, this is done for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS should be like this:

```
var textVal = 0;
function clickMe() {
    if (textVal == 0) {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "TO";
        textVal ++;
    }
    else if (textVal == 1) {
       document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML += " INFINITY";
       textVal += 1;
    }
    else if (textVal == 2) {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML += " AND";
        textVal += 1;
    }
    else if (textVal == 3) {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML += " BEYOND";
        textVal += 1;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "";
        textVal = 0;
    }
};
```

Thats work and i recommend you to read [Clean code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](http://www.amazon.es/Clean-code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882;)

Answer (score 0):

**html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="app2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>  hello  </h1>
  <h1 id="txt"></h1>
  <button onclick="clickMe()">CLICK ME</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**js code**

```
var textVal = 0;
function clickMe() {
    if (textVal == 0) {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "TO";
        textVal += 1;
    }
    else if (textVal == 1) {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML += " INFINITY";
        textVal += 1;
    }
    else if (textVal == 2) {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML += " AND";
        textVal += 1;
    }
    else if (textVal == 3) {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML += " BEYOND";
        textVal += 1;
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "";
        textVal = 0;
    }
}
```